# Objective C should these two return the same value

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

What is the difference of `notificationIdToCancle1` and `notificationIdToCancle2` in the code below:

```
NSDictionary* parameters = (NSDictionary* )parametersObject;
if (parameters != nil) {

    NSString* notificationIdToCancle1 = (NSString* )[parameters objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSString *notificationIdToCancle2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[parameters valueForKey:@"id"]];
}
```

Shouldn't both contain the same value?

Comment: how do you mean _same value_? same pointer? or same content?

Comment: If you have evidence that they do not, please share.

Comment: Yes, they should have the same content. And I should be able to `NSString isEqualToString` assert for two strings for `true`, right?

Comment: Why are you using `objectForKey:` in the 1st line and `valueForKey:` in the 2nd? Those do two completely different things depending on the objects involved.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, I use `objectForKey`: in the 1st line and `valueForKey`: in the 2nd. What is wrong with that?

Comment: Why? If you want to get a value from a dictionary, use `objectForKey:`. Only use `valueForKey:` when you have a specific reason to be using key-value-coding (KVC).

Comment: And you left out a really important detail in your question. What is the actual object returned from `parameters[@"id"]`? Is it really an `NSString` object? Just because you cast it to an `NSString` doesn't mean it really is an `NSString`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString* notificationIdToCancle1 = (NSString* )[parameters objectForKey:@"id"];
```

This line is grabbing the object in the dictionary, casting it to an NSString whether it is or isn't.

```
[NSString* stringWithFormat:@"%@",[parameters valueForKey:@"id"]];
```

This line, I think you have a mistake, you probably don't want the first '*'.  You also probably want to call 'objectForKey:' rather than 'valueForKey:'.  objectForKey: will return the entry in the dictionary, while valueForKey: will use Key Value Coding to return a value.

So:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[parameters objectForKey:@"id"]];
```

This takes the object in the dictionary, runs 'description' on it which returns an NSString instance.  So you definitely get an NSString instance out of it.

Comment: Yes, I agree `*` is a mistake. So first one is a possibly string, the last one is definitely a string?

Comment: Also note you probably want 'objectForKey:' not 'valueForKey' - objectForKey gets you the entry in the dictionary - valueForKey uses key value coding so could return the value of any property on the object it is called against.

Comment: First one is either a string or if not a likely crash soon.  use something like [obj isKindOfClass: [NSString class]] to verify if you wanted to code this in a more dynamic way.

Comment: "First one is either a string or if not a likely crash soon." this is that the makes big difference in my code. Thanks!

Comment: The 2nd line is not likely what you want either. Never rely on the `description` method as a safe way to convert some arbitrary object into an `NSString`.